# Show Character value in Swift 4

Tags: swift, debugging, character, swift4

I'm working on a program that works with `Character`s. The problem is that the debugger shows them as `smallUTF16` values (my guess at least). See image below:

[image]

This behavior is identical in AppCode.

So, how do I make the debugger show me the character in debugging?

Comment: May I ask why not use a `String`, which, as of Swift 4, is considered a `Collection` with an `Element` of `Character`?

Comment: @LeoDabus it shows 97.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook because my data structures (Queue and Stack) use generics. So if I use `String` and then do a `for token in input` that does something with each `Character` separately, it doesn't allow me to `Enqueue` unless I convert it using `String(token)` which is annoying.

Comment: Why don't you just check the printed character in the console?

Comment: @LeoDabus You mean manually printing it out?

Comment: Yes you can also add a custom debugDesceiption to the Characters and print the debugDescription `extension Character {

    var debugDescription: String {
        return String(self) + ": " + String(describing: unicodeScalars.map{$0.value})
    }
    
    
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus The whole point of visual debugging is that I don't have to print all the vars manually, I have a list of vars and their values.

Comment: @LeNguyenDuyAnh I'm figuring it out right now, but that's what the "Summary Format" is for in the debugger (right click a var)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `print` with `terminator` seems to be the problem. If you just want to print the `String` value of each character just change your print statement to:

```
print(c)
```

Or

```
print(String(c))
```

Or

```
print("\(c)")
```

Or

```
print(c.description)
```

Comment: You're completely missing the point. The problem is not printing. The picture even shows that the debugger hasn't reached any printing yet. The problem is that the debugger doesn't show the `Character` value in readable format, it shows the value in smallUTF16 instead.

Comment: So you want to use `Character`s but you want Xcode to pretend they're `String`s?  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: When I print a `Character`, I see "a" (for example). Why wouldn't it make sense for the debugger to not show it?

Answer (score 0):

For the smallUTF16 representation, you can view the UTF16 code points by right-clicking the character's `_representation` > "View Value As" > Vector of uint16:

[image: smallUTF16 as uint16]

Comment: kkkk OP shants to see the Character  itself ("a") in the debugging area not its hexa string

Comment: @LeoDabus Ooops, missed that